# Non-jquery, angularish blur() or focus() after carriage return or softkeyboard "go"

Tags: angularjs

The main issue I'm trying to solve is closing soft keyboards when a user clicks their keyboard's "go" and submits a search form (see below).  If the user clicks the form's submit button, there's no problem because the text field is no longer in focus and the keyboard closes.

I've dug through stackoverflow for answers.  I've seen answers that involve creating directives, controllers, and factories to handle this problem.  Or say 'wait until 1.1' or whatever when angular has built in focus() and blur() directives (which do not address my problem).

I'm currently using a jquery selector (see below) in the Controller method that is triggered on form submission. Simple, but I feel 'dirty' using it and want a better way that doesn't involve 30 lines of code, which is even more ugly IMO than using a jquery selector.

[ng-focus](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angFocus) handles attaching behavior to focus events.  I'm trying to either blur() away from the text box or set focus somewhere.

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left ng-valid ng-dirty">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="submit" data-ng-click="triggerBigO()" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">Invoke Orgasm</button>
    </span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" data-ng-model="search.search_term" class="form-control ng-valid ng-dirty">
  </div>
</form>
<div id="somewhereElse" grass="greener"></div>
```

my ugly solution:

```
PleasureApp.controller("FunTimes", function($scope) {
  $scope.triggerBigO = function() {
    ... do unsavory stuff ...
    $("input").blur();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think angularish way is to create a directive like this and attach it to the form :

```
app.directive('blurOnSubmit', function() {
    return function(scope, form) {
        form.submit(function() {
            form.find(":focus").blur();
        });
    }
});
```

and in html

```
<form ... blur-on-submit> ... </form>
```

It may look a bit overcompilcated but now it is easy to reuse it for other forms as well.

Here is jsfiddle you may try - http://jsfiddle.net/GRaAL/qTWgP/1/